# How to find a non active gameobject in unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to find a gameobject, which is not active in the current scene.It throws Null Reference error.

```
GameObject gameObject;
void start(){
//a non active gameobject tagged with InactiveTag
gameObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("InactiveTag"); 
}
void update(){
if(someCondition){
gameObject.setActive(true); //this line throws Null Reference error
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to find GameObjects that are inactive at start. you have 2 options:

1. You can start with the object active, so the script can find and deactivate it, at start. But, then it has a reference to track.
2. You can create a public var in your script and drag the object in question to the Inspector reference. Then your script will see it whether it active or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a method for getting a reference to an initially inactive object that avoids the overhead of the `Find()` type functions:

```
private GameObject myObject;

void Start()
{
    myObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("MyObject"));
}
```

Your inactive objects must exist in a folder named "Resources" or within a sub-folder of it:

[image: Assets> Resources]

Comment: You can do this without Resources.Load by populating this script with a `public GameObject prefab;` reference to the prefab object to spawn, or with the new Addressables system.

Answer (score 0):

first set a trigger name to the game object

if(trigger.tag == "that game object") {
gameObject.setActive(true); 
}